# Differentiate between multiplication and comment

Tags: parsing, sas, antlr, antlr4

I am writing an ANTLR grammar for SAS and running into an issue where the lexer cannot differentiate between a single line comment and a multiplication operation.

The SAS syntax for comments is regrettably:

```
*message;
or
/*message*/
```

I have written a simple test grammar to illustrate the problem:

```
grammar TEST;

prog: expr* EOF;

expr
: VAR           #base
| expr '*' expr #mult
; 

VAR: ALPHA+;

fragment ALPHA : [a-zA-Z]+ ;

COMMENT: '*' ~[\r\n];

WS: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

I'm not sure how I can qualify the lexer to differentiate between these two situations. I am an ANTLR beginner so I may have missed something obvious.

Comment: And ** is exponent :D

Comment: And don't forget %* is also a comment.

Comment: I am ignoring the macro system except for the most basic substitution. All I need is a limited set of SAS functionality to convert some feature engineering code. No procs, no macros.

Comment: You probably need to add *statement:* to the grammar.  A SAS comment statement will be either `'/*' .*? '*/'` or `'*' .*? ';'`  SAS does not have a line comment, although `* this form of comment is often used as one;`. Except for data lines I believe all SAS source code statements can be multiline (i.e. their inter-token whitespace can be any number of space, tab or newline). Data lines are just 'as-is'

Comment: Don't forget the legacy comment statement, e.g. `data _null_;
comment This is a comment;
cpmment This generates a warning but is also treated as a comment;
comments So does this;
domment This one is treated the start of a do-loop;
put _all_;
run;`